# Git opening Sublime in Windows

Tags: git, sublimetext2

I ran the following instructions and they "worked" perfectly. Actually they did exactly what they said on the box. The issue I have is that when I run a command like git commit I want it to use sublime as the message editor.

> Windows
>
> Find the directory where Sublime is located for you.  For many people,
>   this is C:/Program\ Files/Sublime\ Text\ 2/sublime_text.exe.  To test
>   this, run ls C:/Program\ Files/Sublime\ Text\ 2 within Git Bash.  You
>   should see sublime_text.exe listed.  If you get the error No such file
>   or directory, Sublime is located somewhere else for you and you'll
>   need to find it.  For example, it might be under C:/Program\ Files\
>   (x86)`.
>
> Run the following command in Git Bash: echo 'alias subl="C:/Program\
>   Files/Sublime\ Text\ 2/sublime_text.exe"' >> ~/.bashrc If subl was in
>   a different directory for you in step 1, use that directory.
>
> Close and re-open Git Bash.  Typing subl in Git Bash should now open
>   Sublime.

I know that I should run the command

```
git config --global core.editor "subl"
```

But that then runs the error message below when I try to use git commit

> error: cannot spawn subl: No such file or directory error: unable to
>   start editor 'subl' Please supply the message using either -m or -F
>   option.

Can anyone shed any light on what I should be doing?

Comment: Bash alias's don't work in a `.gitconfig` file. What you were probably thinking of with "subl" was adding it as a variable to your PATH. If you do that you can just put 'subl' in your `.gitconfig` file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the end this worked for me. I ignored the subl alias I had already created.

```
git config --global core.editor 'C:/Program Files/Sublime Text 2/sublime_text.exe -w -n'
```

The -w flag means git bash should wait for the result to come back from Sublime. Without this it will not work. It will open Sublime, but then immediately show an error message.

The -n flag means it will open a new Sublime window. This is very useful as you need to close Sublime for it to add the message back to the git bash terminal and if you have other documents open in that Sublime window you would need to re open another Sublime.

Answer (score 4):

Justin's answer worked for me but I had to use double quotes not single quotes.

```
git config --global core.editor "C:/Program Files/Sublime Text 2/sublime_text.exe -w -n"
```

Comment: Welcome to [StackOverflow]!  I realize that you're too new to add comments on another person's answer, but that would have been the appropriate way to add information like this.  Keep participarting and soon you'll be able to comment!

Answer (score 2):

I changed the / to \ and it worked for me on Windows 10. I am using sublime text 3.

```
git config --global core.editor "C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 3\sublime_text.exe -w -n"
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try the following:

```
    git config --global core.editor "subl -n -w"
```

-n opens up a new window

-w waits for open files to be saved before closing